# I created a class with 3 different maps. I am unable to assign a map iterator to a object's map for some reason

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, maps

I am passing an instance of my class in a function method, but I cannot assign a map iterator to the instance's maps.

For example:

```
bool Graph::isSubGraph(const Graph& g)
{
    map<string, float>::iterator gNodeIt;
    map<pair<string, string>, float>::iterator gEdgeIt;
    cout << g.NodeAmount<<endl; //this works
    gNodeIt = g.Nodes.begin(); //this doesn't work???
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, sorry if this a bad question!

EDIT: Here is the header file for Graph

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <queue> 


class Graph{
private:
    std::map< std::pair<std::string,std::string>, float> EdgeValues;
    std::map< std::string, std::string> Edges; 
    std::map < std::string, float > Nodes; 
    int NodeAmount; 
public:

    //Construct
    Graph();
    //Delete
    ~Graph();
    //Read A Graph From A File
    void readFromFile(std::string file);
    //Write A Graph To A File
    void writeToFile(std::string file);
    //Empty
    bool empty();
    //Add Edge
    void addEdge(std::string v1, std::string v2, int weight);
    //Add Vertex
    void addVertex(std::string name, float val);
    //Count Connected Components
    int numConnectedComponents();
    //Tree Check
    bool tree();
    //Minimum Weight Components
    void minWeightComponent(std::string src);
    //Depth First Search Aux
    bool DFSaux(std::string source, std::string val, bool visited[], std::vector<std::string> cityList);
    //Depth First Search
    bool DFS(std::string source, std::string val);
    //Breadth First Search
    bool BFS(std::string source, std::string val);

    //Closeness
    int closeness(std::string v1, std::string v2);
    //Partition
    bool partitionable();
    //* Subgraph Test
    bool isSubGraph(const Graph& g);
    //Print Valued Path
    void printPathCloseVal(float value);
```

};

Comment: The *full* definition of `Graph` will do *wonders* in assisting you with this question.

Comment: You should provide the code where `Nodes` is defined so we can see if that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter of the function is declared as const Graph& g that is it is a constant reference.

However you are  trying to use non-const iterator and assign to it the const iterator returned by begin for the const object

Change the code the following way

```
bool Graph::isSubGraph(const Graph& g)
{
    map<string, float>::const_iterator gNodeIt;
    map<pair<string, string>, float>::iterator gEdgeIt;
    cout << g.NodeAmount<<endl; //this works
    gNodeIt = g.Nodes.begin(); //this doesn't work???
}
```